# Use custom keyboard shortcuts in the Console

Tags: javascript, console, key

Is there any way to use keyboard shortcuts in the console?

Example: Increment `variable` by one when <kbd>up</kbd> is pressed.

Comment: Where does that `variable` come from? Is it a variable from a running script, in which case you should mention what language that script is using.

Answer (score 0):

**No, you can't**

You could use javascript to implement the keyboards shortcuts (such as var++ when up key is pressed) in the page itself, for debbuging purposes, but that's not possible in the console.

You can check out a list of available Console Commands here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh696634.aspx